# How do I access json object elements from this json in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

I have this Json object and need to consume latitude and longitude

```
Object {
 "coords": Object {
   "accuracy": 22.512498028738957,
   "altitude": 56.650177001953125,
   "altitudeAccuracy": 9.316750526428223,
   "heading": -1,
   "latitude": 44.63884296672757,
   "longitude": -63.59112091788229,
   "speed": -1,
  },
  "timestamp": 1648821089319.792,
}
```

Comment: [There's no JSON anywhere in your question](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: It's an object. There is no such thing as a "JSON object". If the object is stored in `obj` then you would use `obj.coords.latitude`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an object, not json. so you can

```
obj.coords.latitude
```

An example:

```js
let obj = {
  coords: {
   accuracy: 22.512498028738957,
   altitude: 56.650177001953125,
   altitudeAccuracy: 9.316750526428223,
   heading: -1,
   latitude: 44.63884296672757,
   longitude: -63.59112091788229,
   speed: -1,
  },
  timestamp: 1648821089319.792,
}


console.log(obj.coords.latitude)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a `JSON` file, it's an `Object`.

Just save the Object in a variable like `obj` and access it through

`obj.coords.latitude` , or `obj[coords][latitude]`.